# Packery image grid works only when background image is defined in CSS, but not through Javascript. Await/Semaphore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, packery

I have an packery image grid that works and is responsive when the background image of the .item-content is set in the CSS file: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJdapq

```
.item-content {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg);
  border: 4px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
     -moz-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
       -o-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
          transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
}
```

However if I instead remove the hardcoded HTML elements:

```
 <div class="packery" id="packery">

 </div>
```

And try to add these items into the grid dynamically through javascript/jquery when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

             //this block of code below gets executed for around 25 unique image urls 
            //so eventually 25 images would be added to the grid when the page loads


            var imageSourceUrl = //someURL 
            var listingEntry = document.createElement("div");
            listingEntry.className = "item";

            var image = document.createElement("div");
            image.className = "item-content";
            image.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageSourceUrl + ")";
            listingEntry.appendChild(image);

            var grid = document.getElementById("packery");
            grid.appendChild(listingEntry);


 }
```

And this just adds them to the page on the left side rather than in the grid. Any ideas?

Upon further investigating when I add more hardcoded DOM items rather than images added through javascript, the grid when large enough completely overshadows the images. I suspect packery is being initialized before the images get added to the dom.

How can I have packery wait until I initalize all my HTML elements?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was packery was initializing the grid before all my HTML elements were dynamically added. The solution was to simply initialize it after.